# jQuery $.getJSON http request fails, while making the exact same request manually works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, http

Ok, I'm really stuck here.

This is my little test file that I'm using to test a little script I wrote:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.getJSON(
    "/php/banners/check_advertorial.php", 
    { ID : 78 },
    function(data) {
        console.log("callback");
        console.log(data);
        if(data)
            alert("yay");
        else
            alert("nay");   
    }
);
</script>
```

This is what check_advertorial.php looks like, I simplified it for testing purposes.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode(true); 
?>
```

So I monitor the requests in Chrome, and the call to check_advertorial fails, no response. Not even an error code. But if I copy the request URL, and just paste it into the browser, I get a successful request and it prints "true".

What gives?

UPDATE:
I have tested it in different browsers.

- Chrome: Original test platform
- Chrome Canary: No Change
- Firefox: Works as expected
- Internet Explorer 10: No Change

UPDATE 2:
As Hüseyin BABAL pointed out, ABP blocked the request because it had the word "advertorial" in it.

Comment: No errors in your console? Maybe add `.fail` to see what you get back. Because it might fail.

Comment: Just the one that says the GET request failed.

Comment: Are you sure your URL is correct? What do you type in if you test the URL in the browser? And is this page you are showing in the root of your website?

Comment: I literally copy the URL that I get when I click the failed request in dev tools. Here, you can play with it yourself: http://www.healthylivingmagazine.us/php/banners/test.php

Comment: Can you see that your request sent? What do you mean with it fails? What is the response code

Comment: @Nikzilla check the console. I get an error from your AJAX page: `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL Yes, but it doesn't give a response code. Just says failed. http://i.imgur.com/6eESXri.png

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Wtf. I'm staring at the console. I have no idea how you're getting that.

Comment: The file that contains above jquery code is in same location with check_advertorial.php? Please share your folder structure also

Comment: @Nikzilla I'm using Chrome 33 on OSX if it helps

Comment: By the way, I have test healthylivingmagazine.us/php/banners/test.php , it alerts yay

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL Yes it's in the same directory. Requesting it directly didn't make a difference though. There is no doubt in the URL being wrong, because, like I said, if you copy and paste the request URL, it loads successfully.

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL DAFAQ. What browser? I'm going to test in other browsers now. This is weird.

Comment: I have tested in chrome

Comment: I just tested different browsers. Updated the original post.

Comment: @Nikzilla, I have stated in my answer also, are you using adblock plugin on your browser?

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL SONUVABICH. Turned off ABP, worked like a charm.

Comment: @Nikzilla Upvote and confirm answer would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add status check code to your query in order to detect your request fails or not;

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "/php/banners/check_advertorial.php", {ID:78}, function(data) {
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log("callback");
            console.log(data);
            if(data)
                alert("yay");
            else
                alert("nay");  
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "error occured: " + err );
  });
```

**Edit:** Also be sure that you are not using adblock plugin

Comment: Why does it need to be in document ready? It doesn't have to wait for anything.

Comment: yep, changes nothing, just tested.

Comment: Because your function is not triggered. You need to triggere it by putting it on an even like when document loaded, when document rady, or assign it to and element as event. If you do not want to run your script before document ready, you need to use above code

Comment: You only need the document ready if you're referencing DOM elements.

Comment: -1 owner, what is your reason to that vote? I have provide possible solution

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Your solution makes no sense. Everything in `<script>` blocks is executed when the page is loaded. You only need to put something in an event handler if you want it to be delayed until that event occurs.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL you haven't. In this form, `$.getJSON(...)` is run when it's read.

Comment: If you need code to be in a document ready, how does the `$(document).ready()` expression get executed, since it's not _in_ the document ready?

Comment: Ok, I have understood that request never been sent. I have updated my answer to response status check

Comment: I tested the code. Nothing changed. Here is your console output: "error occured: error,"